Prove that the conditional von Neumann entropy satisfies $S(A|C)=-S(A|B)$ if computed on a pure $\rho_{ABC}$
Can someone show me how to prove this relation?

If $\rho_{ABC}$ is a pure state, then $S(A|C)=-S(A|B)$

I already know that $S(A|B)=S(\rho_{AB})-S(\rho_{B})$ and that I should somehow use that $S(\rho_{A})=S(\rho_{B})$ if $\rho_{AB}$ is a pure state.

First, we have using the formula for the conditional entropy, we have :
$$S(A|C) + S(A|B) = S(\rho_{AB}) + S(\rho_{AC}) - S(\rho_C) - S(\rho_B)$$
Then, as $\rho_{ABC}$ is a pure state, we know that we have $S(\rho_{AB}) = S(\rho_C)$ and $S(\rho_{AC}) = S(\rho_B)$. The equations above therefore simplifies to :
$$S(A|C) + S(A|B) = 0$$
